# Looping through a set of HTML form elements to get the current values in an object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, backbone.js, underscore.js

Taking from a HTML setup that looks like this:

```
   <nav data-filters class="">

        <input type="radio" name="type" value="company" checked>Company
        <input type="radio" name="type" value="product">Product
        <input type="radio" name="type" value="service">Service

        <select name="category_1" multiple>
            <option value="a" selected>a</option>
            <option value="b">b</option>
            <option value="c" selected>c</option>
        </select>

        <select name="category_2" multiple>
            <option value="a" selected>a</option>
            <option value="b" selected>b</option>
            <option value="c">c</option>
        </select>

        <input type="radio" name="startswith" value="a" checked>a
        <input type="radio" name="startswith" value="b">b
        <input type="radio" name="startswith" value="c">c
        <input type="radio" name="startswith" value="num">#

        <input name="keyword" type="text">

    </nav>
```

The goal is to achieve this result:

```
obj = {

   "type": {
        "values": [
            "company"
        ]
    },
    "category_1": {
        "values": [
            "a",
            "c"
        ]
    },
    "category_2": {
        "values": [
            "a",
            "b"
        ]
    },
    "startswith": {
        "values": [
            "a"
        ]
    }
}
```

This is my current setup ( **note:** this.$el just refers to $(nav) ):

```
        var obj = {};

        this.$el.find('[name]').each(function(i, input) {

                var val     = (function() {
                                if ( input.type == "radio" || input.type == "checkbox" )
                                    return $(input).filter(':checked').val();

                                return $(input).val()
                                })(),
                    name    = input.name;

                if (val) {
                    obj[name] = {
                        values: _.flatten([val]) // Always return an array
                    }
                }
            });

        return obj;
```

This seems error prone, and I don't think it's the best way to do it. 
How should I really be doing this?

**Notes on the background of this question:** 
I'm building a small directory with backbone. This happens in the `Filters` view, where the current criteria is turned into an object, which is going to be passed to the collection as data for the fetch() function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$.serializeArray` method (https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) to serialize your form into an array of names and values. Then you just need to convert the result to the desired form:

```
var inputs = $('nav :input').serializeArray();
var obj = {};
_.each(inputs, function(val){
  if(obj[val.name]){
     obj[val.name].values.push(val.value);
  }else{
    obj[val.name] = {values: [val.value]};
  }
});
```

JSBin demo: http://jsbin.com/zidanata/2/edit?html,js,console

Comment: You don't need the `<form>` and that `<nav>` might be one part of a larger `<form>` so that structure might not be practical. You can say things like `$('nav :input').serializeArray()` though: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/TR77J/

Comment: You're right - thank you for pointing this. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: You could also `var obj = _(inputs).reduce(function(h, val) { ... }, { })` if you didn't want to predeclare `obj`. `serializeArray` is the main point though, `_.each` vs `_.reduce` isn't terribly important.